# Is there any algorithm to pass from a circular permutation to another by minimizing number of adjacent swaps?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, circular-dependency

I'm looking for an algorithm which, given two circular permutations (the first and the last element are considered as adjacent), minimizes the number of adjacent swaps to pass from a permutation to another.

Is there any well-known solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Are 123 and 231 considered the same permutation?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I would assume not, but you can get from 123 to 321 with one swap.

Comment: @btilly that'd be my guess as well, but that's not the usual definition: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html

Comment: Yes, 123 and 231 are considered the same permutation. The last and the first element are considered adjacent.

Comment: There's an algorithm due to Jerrum: https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(85)90047-7

Comment: Is there a solution in terms of code?